# What is the center of $Z_2\wr Z_2\wr\cdot\cdot\cdot\wr Z_2$, here $Z_2$ denotes a cyclic group of order 2?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, wreath-product

What is the center of $Z_2\wr Z_2\wr\cdot\cdot\cdot\wr Z_2$ which is the wreath product of $Z_2$ $r$ times, here $Z_2$ denotes a cyclic group of order 2?

When $r=2$, I know that $Z_2\wr Z_2\cong D_4$ which is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_4$ and $Z(Z_2\wr Z_2)=Z_2$.

I also know that in general $Z_2\wr Z_2\wr\cdot\cdot\cdot\wr Z_2$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_{2^r}$, I wonder if  $Z(Z_2\wr Z_2\wr\cdot\cdot\cdot\wr Z_2)=Z_2$ for any $r\geq2$?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: No, it is not a dihedral group.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564194/the-automorphism-group-of-the-complete-binary-rooted-tree-of-height-3

Comment: Yes, the centre always has order two. That's not hard to prove by induction on the number of wreath factors.

Comment: For more details on the argument, see [Derek's older comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285032/11619).

Comment: Thank you very much!